# Fetch loading in data for HTML

Tags: javascript, fetch

So I'm making a simple pokemon app where the front-end makes fetch calls to grab the Pokemon from PokeAPI and displays it, but when loading a pokemon you can see that the fetch info gets loaded at different rates.
For example the pokemon loads then the name loads then the background loads then the type loads.
Is there anyway to have it so the HTML fills all at one time?

This is what my Javascript fetch function looks like, additionally here is the app so you can see how the information loads slowly / not all at once : https://bui-pokemon.herokuapp.com/

```
pokeButton.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
e.preventDefault();

const pokeNameSearch = pokeSearch.value.toLowerCase();

fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeNameSearch}`)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then(data => {
    if(pokeCard.classList.value === 'poke_card'){
        pokeCard.classList.add('border');
    };

    //If a pokemon was normal / flying type then flying should be shown in the background isntead of normal
    //because flying type is more of a defining characteristic of that pokemon rather than normal
    if(data.types.length > 1 && data.types[0].type.name === "normal" && data.types[1].type.name === "flying"){
        pokeCard.className = `poke_card border ${data.types[1].type.name}_background`
    } else {
        pokeCard.className = `poke_card border ${data.types[0].type.name}_background`;
    }
    
    pokeImg.src = data.sprites.front_default;
    pokeName.innerHTML = data.name;

    // Fill in Pokemon Type
    pokeTypeIcon1.src = "";
    pokeTypeIcon2.src = "";
    pokeTypeIcon1.className = '';
    pokeTypeIcon2.className = '';
    pokeTypeIcon2.style.display = "none";

    pokeType.innerHTML = `${data.types[0].type.name}`;
    pokeNumDisplay.innerHTML = `#${fillInZero(data.id.toString())}`
    pokeTypeIcon1.src = `img/icons/${data.types[0].type.name}.svg`
    pokeTypeIcon1.className = `type_icon_1 ${data.types[0].type.name}`
    
    if(data.types.length > 1){
        pokeType.innerHTML += `/${data.types[1].type.name}`
        
        pokeTypeIcon2.src = `img/icons/${data.types[1].type.name}.svg`
        pokeTypeIcon2.style.display = "inline-block";
        pokeTypeIcon2.className = `type_icon_2 ${data.types[1].type.name}`
        
    } else {
        pokeType.innerHTML = `${data.types[0].type.name}`
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you have any code you can share?

Comment: https://github.com/brianbui012/Pokedex

Comment: You need to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question itself.

Comment: @Daniel_Knights There we go, I deployed my app so you can see what is happening with my code. Thanks!

Comment: You load the information at the same rate, it looks "uneven" because it takes some time to render the text in that font and to load the image for the client. If you load a pokemon one, it is quicker to open it the second time.

You could either load all of them at once or just place a spinner until everything is rendered.

Comment: @elvinas Do you know any guides or what to search up for a loader that covers the HTML so it gives it time to load?

Comment: Just put all the html items that you update in a container. Then hide the container when you start loading data. Unhide it again after all the fields are set.

Comment: @Kielstra That's an awesome idea. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the font and images loading causes the issue.

What you could do, is listen for the [`load`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) event on each image and transition the opacity. Then, use [`document.fonts.ready`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fonts#Doing_operation_after_all_fonts_are_loaded) and transition the color:

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const background = document.getElementById("background")
const imgOne = document.getElementById("img-one")
const imgTwo = document.getElementById("img-two")

const fadeIn = (el) => {
  el.addEventListener("load", () => el.style.opacity = "1")
}

document.fonts.ready.then(() => container.style.color = "#fff")

fadeIn(background)
fadeIn(imgOne)
fadeIn(imgTwo)

background.src = "https://ak.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/9589454/thumb/2.jpg"
imgOne.src = "https://toppng.com/public/uploads/thumbnail/ikachu-8-bits-8-bit-pokemon-grid-11563233054e4sqfqyl2l.png"
imgTwo.src = "https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/lightning-icon.png"
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap');
body {
  background: #43464b;
  font-family: "Press Start 2P", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: color 0.25s;
}

.container>*:not(#background) {
  z-index: 1;
}

img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

#background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#img-one,
#img-two {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img id="background" />
  <img id="img-one" />
  <p>#25 Pikachu</p>
  <img id="img-two" />
  <p>Electric</p>
</div>
```

---

However, it could still be uneven this way if one thing takes longer to load than the other.

Another solution is to push values to an array once loaded, and check the length of the array before setting the opacity of the container:

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const background = document.getElementById("background")
const imgOne = document.getElementById("img-one")
const imgTwo = document.getElementById("img-two")

const loaded = []

const setLoadState = (el) => {
  loaded.push(el)

  if (loaded.length === 4)
    container.style.opacity = "1"
}
const imgLoad = (img) => {
  img.addEventListener("load", () => setLoadState(img.id))
}

document.fonts.ready.then(() => setLoadState('font'))
imgLoad(background)
imgLoad(imgOne)
imgLoad(imgTwo)

background.src = "https://ak.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/9589454/thumb/2.jpg"
imgOne.src = "https://toppng.com/public/uploads/thumbnail/ikachu-8-bits-8-bit-pokemon-grid-11563233054e4sqfqyl2l.png"
imgTwo.src = "https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/lightning-icon.png"
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap');
body {
  background: #43464b;
  font-family: "Press Start 2P", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

.container>*:not(#background) {
  z-index: 1;
}

#background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#img-one,
#img-two {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img id="background" />
  <img id="img-one" />
  <p>#25 Pikachu</p>
  <img id="img-two" />
  <p>Electric</p>
</div>
```